# Information gathering in Ubuntu and Backtrack

Tags: ubuntu, networking

There was a program in Backtrack OS where we could give a domain name or an Email and it would search the Internet for all the information available in "Whois" result's all websites and made connection's to them.

Using this program, I could search an Email and find on what websites it was used and stuff like that.

anybody know this program? i want it for Ubuntu 15.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're referring to [Maltego](https://www.paterva.com/web6/products/maltego.php), it's used for connecting the dots between people/websites etc.